# User reference in error message?

Tags: discussion, error-message

I realize this is particularly nitpicky but I recently edited a post and submitting it resulted in the following error message:

```
It looks like your post is mostly code; add some more details.
```

Technically shouldn't it refer to the '*user*'s post' and/or 'your *edit*' since it isn't *my* post?